# Kotlin data classes and nullable types

Tags: android, kotlin, data-class

I'm new to Kotlin and I don't know why compiler complains about this code:

```
data class Test(var data : String = "data")

fun test(){
  var test: Test? = Test("")
  var size = test?.data.length
}
```

Compiler complains with `test?.data.length`, it says that I should do: `test?.data?.length`. But data variable is `String`, not `String?`, so I don't understand why I have to put the `?` when I want to check the length.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The expression `test?.data.length` is equivalent to `(test?.data).length`, and the `test?.data` part is nullable: it is either `test.data` or `null`. Therefore it is not null-safe to get its `length`, but instead you should use the [safe call operator](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/null-safety.html#safe-calls) again: `test?.data?.length`.

The nullability is propagated through the whole calls chain: you have to write these chains as `a?.b?.c?.d?.e` (which is, again, equivalent to `(((a?.b)?.c)?.d)?.e`), because, if one of the left parts is null, the rest of the calls cannot be performed as if the value is not-null.

Comment: Ok, I understand now. Thanks you very much!

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to use safe call before each non-nullable component of the call chain, you can get the result of the first safe call into a new variable with the standard extension functions `run` or `let`:

```
// `this` is non-nullable `Test` inside lambda 
val size = test?.run { data.length }   

// or: `it` is non-nullable `Test` inside lambda
val size = test?.let { it.data.length }
```

Note that `size` is still nullable `Int?` here.

Comment: Thanks you very much!